# Misleading description of 40 days and nights leading to the eigel?

Tags: parashat-ki-tisa, mishpatim

The final passuk in Mishpatim [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.24.18):

> וַיָּבֹ֥א מֹשֶׁ֛ה בְּת֥וֹךְ הֶעָנָ֖ן וַיַּ֣עַל אֶל־הָהָ֑ר וַיְהִ֤י
> מֹשֶׁה֙ בָּהָ֔ר אַרְבָּעִ֣ים י֔וֹם וְאַרְבָּעִ֖ים לָֽיְלָה׃ {פ}
>
> Moses went inside the cloud and ascended the mountain; and Moses remained on
> the mountain forty days and forty nights.

Note that "days" appears before "nights" here.

In Ki Tisa, it [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.32.1) that the story of the eigel started because:

> וַיַּ֣רְא הָעָ֔ם כִּֽי־בֹשֵׁ֥שׁ מֹשֶׁ֖ה לָרֶ֣דֶת מִן־הָהָ֑ר
> וַיִּקָּהֵ֨ל הָעָ֜ם עַֽל־אַהֲרֹ֗ן וַיֹּאמְר֤וּ אֵלָיו֙ ק֣וּם ׀
> עֲשֵׂה־לָ֣נוּ אֱלֹהִ֗ים אֲשֶׁ֤ר יֵֽלְכוּ֙ לְפָנֵ֔ינוּ כִּי־זֶ֣ה ׀
> מֹשֶׁ֣ה הָאִ֗ישׁ אֲשֶׁ֤ר הֶֽעֱלָ֙נוּ֙ מֵאֶ֣רֶץ מִצְרַ֔יִם לֹ֥א
> יָדַ֖עְנוּ מֶה־הָ֥יָה לֽוֹ׃
>
> When the people saw that Moses was so long in coming down from the
> mountain, the people gathered against Aaron and said to him, “Come,
> make us a god who shall go before us, for that fellow Moses—the man
> who brought us from the land of Egypt—we do not know what has happened
> to him.”

Rashi there explains that the reason for their mistake was that they thought the first day - i.e. the day he went up the mountain - should count as day one. In fact, they should have begun counting the next day as day one.

In light of this, shouldn't the passuk in Mishpatim have been written in the same order as in Bereishit (ויהי ערב ויהי בוקר) and said:

> ארבעים לילה וארבעים יום
>
> 40 nights and 40 days

Why does the passuk use the backward language that allows for this error in interpretation? The exact use of this phrase in Mishpatim is told to us in past tense (not to the people in the desert in the present), but did the people make their mistake because they were told the numbers in the same way?

Comment: I asked several local rabbis and Torah scholars this question, and one of them told me that he saw a source that explains that yes, this is why they made a mistake, but he did not remember where he saw that. The others all told me they've never seen the question discussed anywhere.